# Importing Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, import, gradle

I'm trying to import a previously made AS project on a new PC. I am running into severe issues however. De android view of the project structure is completely empty. As soon as the project is imported I get a "Frameworks detected" message, telling me that it has detected an Android framework. As I tell it to use the Android framework the android view shows only two things: The application name and an empty java folder. When I take a look inside the module via project structure there are a lot more folders but they aren't displayed.

I've tried both importing and opening the project but neither seems to work.

Comment: Could there be some form of version mismatch? e.g. if it's an old project and you're using a newer version of AS and the Android Gradle plugin?

Comment: You should find some error message somewhere. Check "Messages" or "Event Log" on the bar at the bottom with "Android,Run, Todo.."

Comment: @will421 There is no "Messages" button on the bottom bar. The only available buttons are "Terminal", "TODO", "Event Log" and "Gradle Console".

Comment: @J Heikes Try Gradle Console. When I had this error and nothing was displaying, it was an error during gradle synchro

Comment: @will421 The console is completely blank.

Comment: @JHeikes And the sync does nothing ?

Comment: @will421, Nope. Tried rebuilding the project as well but no dice either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I more or less figured out why it's acting so oddly. Somehow all of the references of the project got changed to the location of where the code is currently stored during the backup proces. I ended up copying the code from its original location to the online storage again and now it's working.